# Git Push to a remote branch with directory

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I'm trying to push to a remote branch with a directory(I can't remove the directory or change the remote branch structure).

How can I push to this branch? I've already tried this command `git push origin release/Release_1.0` and lots of variations.

This is the outcome:

```
$ git push origin release/Release_1.0
error: src refspec releaseRelease_1.0 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Pankwood/LearningGit.git'
```

This is my branch structure:

```
 git branch --all
  dev
* master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/release/Release_1.0
```

[Github structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYJZg.png)

Comment: *"I've already tried ..."* - And what was the outcome? Usually git messages are pretty verbose and helpful.

Comment: I've added the outcome to the post. tks

Comment: `release\Release_1.0` is not `release/Release_1.0`. Different slash.

Comment: I've tried this one too. Same error.

Comment: I've edited the post fixing the slash.

Comment: What is the output of `git branch`?  The error indicates that you have no local branch with the specified name, so there's nothing to push.  (As an aside your terminology - "branch with directory" - is unclear.  I assume you mean that the branch name has a slash in it; that is typically referred to as a namespace.)

Comment: When I said "branch with directory" I meant this `.git\refs\remotes\origin\release\Release_1.0`. Usually, I have this scenery `.git\refs\remotes\origin\master` or `.git\refs\remotes\yourbranchname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message indicates that you have no branch in your local repository named `release/Release_1.0`

If this branch exists on the remote, you can `git checkout origin/release/Release_1.0`, perform your work, commit your changes, and then `git push origin release/Release_1.0`

tl;dr It looks like that branch was never created on your local repository.

Comment: You are right! I didn't know I must have a local repository with the same name of the remote repository. To solve this problem I execute the following commands: `git checkout -b release/Release_1.0` and `git push origin release/Release_1.0`

Comment: Now I'm wondering if this affirmation is true: **I must have a local repository with the same name of the remote repository**. I mean, is there any way to push to this weird remote branch without creating a local repository with the same name?

Comment: I've found out I don't need to create a local repository with the same name. I run the command below and it works very well: `git push origin dev:release/Release_1.0`

Answer (score 1):

you can firstly change to the branch you want to publish in this case you have to do this...

`git branch <branch>
git checkout -b <branch>
git add .
git commit "Your commit"
git push -u origin <branch>`

in this case  will be **remotes/origin/release/Release_1.0** or  **remotes\origin\release\Release_1.0**